# Jquery masked input in asp.net

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I have two asp.net textboxes I need code for input mask with time format and also for date format. Please provide url of jquery file also. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="date" />
<input type="text" id="time" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
    $("#time").mask("99:99");
});
```

Read http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo See [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

`Download the latest` from [github repo](https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/qnGd5/)

Comment: This can make time vulnerable to "59:60" for example.